# undefined method `id' for false:FalseClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The error (`undefined method 'id' for false:FalseClass`) is referencing this line:

```
if current_user && current_user.admin? || current_user.id == id.to_i
```

Why is this producing an error? Shouldn't it not reach `current_user.id` if the first `&&` condition fails?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The expression

```
current_user && current_user.admin? || current_user.id == id.to_i
```

Is parsed as the following

```
(current_user && current_user.admin?) || (current_user.id == id.to_i)
```

So, when current_user is false, the evaluation goes something like

```
(false && current_user.admin?) || ?
(false)                        || ?
                                  (false.id == id.to_i)
                               # \\ KABOOM! //
```

It should probably be expressed as the following, with parenthesis, in which methods are only invoked against current_user if it's a not false/nil.

```
current_user && (current_user.admin? || current_user.id == id.to_i)
```

Alternatively, consider using other flow control structures like `if` and/or discrete methods encapsulating the logic.

---

It is also odd that current_user can be `false`: `nil` would likely be more fitting when there is "no current user"..

Comment: You should suggest in your answer the correct way to do it, i.e. `A && (B || C)`

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm using Sorcery, so I didn't write `current_user`.

Comment: +1 to the suggestion that `current_user` should not return nil and not false.